# How to find out if a file exists in C# / .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, io

I would like to test a string containing a path to a file for existence of that file (something like the `-e` test in Perl or the `os.path.exists()` in Python) in C#.

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Use:

```
File.Exists(path)
```

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx

Edit: In System.IO

Comment: File.Exists(path) returns false even if the file exists BUT caller lacks permission to read it. Is there a different way to handle this kind of situations and check whether a file exists even if the caller cannot read it?

Comment: @ADTC: from a security point of view it sounds normal that it works that way, from a developer point of view, it may make things more complicated. Do you get an exception in that case if you try to create a file?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unable to answer your question now as this was on an old project. I suppose it should throw an exception since a lack of reading permission should mean a lack of over-writing permission too. But not sure.

Comment: @ADTC just stumbled by and thought I might mention drop-box directories.  Those can be set up where you have create or write permission but no read permission. Not that it is relevant to this question directly, just that they are not as odd as one might think.

Comment: Side note: File.Exists returns False on Google Drive File Stream G: drive, if the casing of path does not exactly match what is actually on G:. Usually on any physical drive casing does not matter, so I wonder, is there something amiss with the Exists method?

Comment: What if the file name contains a wildcard?

Comment: @CTZStef that's the quirk of the google's virtual drive rather than of the framework method.

Answer (score 78):

[System.IO.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx):

```
using System.IO;

if (File.Exists(path)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("file exists");
}
```

Answer (score 30):

System.IO.File.Exists(path)

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

Give full path as input. Avoid relative paths.

```
 return File.Exists(FinalPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use WinForms and my way to use File.Exists(string path) is the next one:

```
public bool FileExists(string fileName)
{
    var workingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    var file = $"{workingDirectory}\{fileName}";
    return File.Exists(file);
}
```

fileName **must** include the extension like `myfile.txt`

Comment: use Path.Combine

Comment: Needs \\ between dir and file:
var file = $"{workingDirectory}\\{fileName}";

Comment: you're right. I missed one more char @Mike

Answer (score 0):

```
File.Exists(Path.Combine(_workDir, _file));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.