# C#'s equivalent to Python's os.path.exists()?

Tags: c#, python, exists

I can use os.path.exists() to check if the file exists or not with Python.
What's the equivalent function in C#?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960/how-to-find-out-if-a-file-exists-in-c-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `System.IO.File` and `System.IO.Directory` has `Exists`.

```
bool dirExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"C:\directory\");
bool fileExists = System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\directory\file.txt");
```

And for an additional bonus: Note that for cross platform compatibility you should use for example `System.IO.Path.Combine("c:", "directory", "file.txt");`. This will automatically join the parts of the directory using `System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`. Of course only Windows has C:, so you need to know what to use as the root of the drive.

Answer (score 3):

Surely you mean .NET, not C# :)

Try [System.IO.File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

```
System.IO.File.Exists(@"c:\path\to\your\file.ext");
```