# Move file when it is available

Tags: java, c#, file-io

I am using this code to move files in row in my C# application.

```
public static bool IsFileReady(String sFilename)
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream inputStream = File.Open(sFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
        {
            if (inputStream.Length > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
while (Checker.bFileIsFileReady(sFilename))
{
    //Do work here
    break;
}
```

Can you please tell me, how I can translate this code to java? Right now, my java application works with Thread.Sleep()...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if a file exists? (Java on Windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-java-on-windows)

Comment: I want to check if file was completely moved. checking for existence is not the problem

Comment: To see if it's moved, wouldn't you check if the file is in the new location and out of the old location? There is no way to look at a File object and see if it was once moved before.

Comment: It should be checked, if the moved file in the new location is completely on the disc and e.g. writtable

Comment: Please check if [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java) question helps you. Regards

Comment: I don't know. The FileChannels look like they are only to copy files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out if a file exists in C# / .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960/how-to-find-out-if-a-file-exists-in-c-sharp-net)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to copy file, you need input and output stream. but if you just want to move it, you can use `File.renameTo`

```
File from = new File(oldFile);
File to = new File(newFileName);
from.renameTo(to);
```