# In SftpClient how can i check if the file has been donwlonded in directory or not?

Tags: c#

I am downloading from SFTP and want to check if the file exists in the folder "directory @"D:..." or not

```
 using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(Host, Port, Username, Password))

            {
                sftp.Connect();

                var files = sftp.ListDirectory(RemoteFileName);

                string downloadFileNames = string.Empty;

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (file.FullName.EndsWith(".gz"))
                    {
                        using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(Path.Combine(directory, file.Name)))
                        {

                            sftp.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fileStream);
                        }
                    }
                    downloadFileNames += file.Name;
                }
            }
```

Comment: [File.Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out if a file exists in C# / .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960/how-to-find-out-if-a-file-exists-in-c-sharp-net)

Comment: Are you attempting to verify that the file you download exists?

Comment: Use the overload of `DownloadFile` that lets you supply a callback. The callback will be called when the file is complete and you can set a flag or display a message at that time.

Comment: @JohnWu your idea is very good . could you show me some code how is doing that please ?

Comment: @Martin yes i am trying to do that. i don't want evey time to download the same files i want to check if its arleady downloaded then not download it again

Comment: @BenOmran Thank you for clarifying that.  Based on what you said, I've provided an answer below

Comment: @BenOmran what SFTP library are you using?

Comment: @RamblinRose SshNet library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> i don't want evey time to download the same files i want to check if
>   its arleady downloaded then not download it again

I am assuming that you want to only download files that you have not previously downloaded.

In order to achieve this, use `File.Exists` to verify whether you already downloaded the file to a location:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    if (file.FullName.EndsWith(".gz"))
    {
        var targetFilename = Path.Combine(directory, file.Name);

        if (!File.Exists(targetFilename))
        {
            using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(targetFilename))
            {
                sftp.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fileStream);
            }
            downloadFileNames += file.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

This verifies whether the target file exists *before* downloading it from the SFTP server.